# Disable No data to display message

Tags: r, shiny, r-highcharter

I have a chart in Shiny generated with the HighCharter package. I would like to surpress the "No data to display" message which is shown when the series to be plotted is empty. In my case, the actual *content* of the plot is shown as a `plotLines` (variable `age` below). However, in order for HighCharter to display the plotLines, it needs data. This is the reason, why I add the line (remove that line to see what I mean):

`%>% hc_series(list(data=c(), visible=FALSE, id="dummy"))`

Can this be done?

Here is a sample using `reprex(venue="r")`: I would like that the background gradient and the plotLines are showed but the message "No data to display" should be hidden.

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
#> Highcharts (www.highcharts.com) is a Highsoft software product which is
#> not free for commercial and Governmental use

# layout
ui <-   fluidPage(highchartOutput("highchart_slider", height = "200px"))

server <- function(input, output) { 
  # This value comes from the backend and is variable. It is in [-100, 100]
  age <- 20

  output$highchart_slider <- renderHighchart({
    hcSlider <- highchart() %>%
      hc_chart(renderTo= "container", 
               defaultSeriesType = 'bar', 
               plotBackgroundColor=list(
                 linearGradient = list(x1=0, x2=1, y1=0, y2=0), 
                 stops=list(list(0, '#bf0000'),list(0.45, '#e1e218'), 
                            list(0.55, '#e1e218'),list(1, 'darkgreen')))) %>%
      hc_yAxis(tickInterval=100, min=-100, max=100,
               plotLines=list(list(
                 label = list(text = "title", align = 'center', verticalAlign = 'top'),  
                 color = "black", width = 4, value = age, y = -2))
      ) %>%
      hc_series(list(data=c(), visible=FALSE, id="dummy"))
    # display plot
    hcSlider
  })
  }

# start the app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

#' <!--html_preserve-->

#' Shiny applications not supported in static R Markdown documents

#' <!--/html_preserve-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has no reproducible example, but as I understand, you want to prevent a plot to be plotted, whenever no data is available?

I would advice looking into `req()`
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/req.html

If you  want a plot to be only plotted when let's say `data` is available, 
do:

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
  req(data)
  ...
})
```

req will not only stop the plot when the data is `NULL` or `FALSE`, but also when the user has no data selected

Comment: Added an example. I would like to show the plot (has background, fixed lines etc.) even when no data is available. I just want to surpress the message "No data to display".

Comment: @Damian, your example doesnt have any data, please provide some

Comment: @Damian would you mind using `reprex::reprex( venue = "r")` in order to provide your reproducible example(your dummy data).

Comment: @PorkChop, @Ann I added some context to the question and added a reproducible example using `reprex(venue="r")`.

Comment: What is `c()`?, this is the data im referring to

Comment: It's an empty list. If I drop the `hc_series()`, the plotLines will magically disappear as well, that's why I need it. I could also write: `hc_series(list(visible=FALSE, id="dummy"))`

Comment: Go to htmlwidgets > highchart.yaml  then commented out modules/no-data-to-display.js . commenting out this line should disable "No data to display" message.